# Firebase import export JSON not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I create a collection in Firebase as shown in the picture:

[image]

In the old version, there was a three button in the top, where you can import and export data as JSON and other types, but now I can't find it.

Does the tool change this action (import/export) or I should to do some configuration to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the old version, there was a three button in the top, where you can import and export data as JSON and other types, but now I can't find it.

What you're describing is for Firebase Realtime Database.  That import feature is still present for that database product.  However, the database you're working with now is Firestore, which is a completely different database product, and does not have an import feature.  You will have to write code to import data, or find some other way to do so - it's not possible from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to export/import this on your own.

Documents for [Exporting and importing data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import)